# Is there any bash symbol that represent 'that' directory?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, directory

For example when i am in directory A, i want to do change to a files in directory B, and save the changes in B, the only way i know now is

```
A$ cat B/file |some_changes > B/file2
```

Is there any symbols to replace B in the 'B/file2',
like `.` means this directory, is there any for 'that' directory?
I think of this when i got a very long directory B. Tks

Comment: No. Just use a variable if it's something you'll need repeatedly.

Comment: Or you might want to `pushd B` & then `popd`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use history expansion for this but getting it right is tricky and almost certainly not worth the effort.

```
$ cat B/file | some_change > !#:1:h/file2
```

Where `!#` is history expansion for the current line `:1` is word one of the expansion and `:h` is the "head" of the file path.

Alternatively both suggestions in the comments are good.

Finally you could use readline/etc. commands to cut the path and then paste it again.

Use `meta-b`/`alt-b` to jump back to the long path, then `ctrl-w` to kill (cut) the word/path then `ctrl-y` to yank (put) it back, then `ctrl-e` to jump to the end of the line and `ctrl-y` to paste the long path again.